# date appear as {01-01-0001 12:00:00 AM} when i press submit putton

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

So i have model that have datetime in it but its actually date only

this what inside my model

```
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
 public DateTime TrDate { get; set; }
```

when i enter the page first time i want the @Html.EditorFor to show current date so i do this in my controllers :

```
model.TrDate = (DateTime.Now.Date);
```

then in my view :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TrDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "date", @id = "TrDateInput" } })
```

but every time i press submit its show {01-01-0001 12:00:00 AM}

i also put this in the start of my view :

```
CultureInfo usCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = usCulture;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = usCulture;
```

beacuse it show hijir date and i want en-US

and i put this in my startup page :

```
 CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
 CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

put it seem that there is problem i keep trying different thing but nothing work

my computer date is 14-09-2023 maybe the problem there ??

i tried everything  i come across

--Edit My code :

---

```
 public class MasterM()
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
      
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

        public DateTime TrDate { get; set; }}
-----------------------

    @model WebApplication6.Models.MasterM

    @using System.Globalization

    @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

    @{

   

    CultureInfo usCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = usCulture;
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = usCulture;

   

     }




    <hr />

    <form method="post" asp-action="Create1" asp-controller="MasterM">

    
 
 

       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="TrDate" class="control-label"></label>
                    @*    <input asp-for="TrDate" class="form-control" />*@
                    @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TrDate)*@
                    @*   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TrDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
    
                    @*<span asp-validation-for="TrDate" class="text-danger"></span>*@
    
    
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TrDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "date", @id = "TrDateInput" } })
    
                    @*  asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" type="date" data-val-culture="en-US" *@
    
                    @*<div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="TrDate"></label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input asp-for="TrDate" class="form-control" />
    
                            </div>
                            <span asp-validation-for="TrDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>*@
    
                </div>
            </div>
      
        </div>
    
    
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" id="save-button" value="Create1" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
    
    
    
                </div> 
            </div>
        
    
    </form>
    
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

-----------------------------Controllers

    public ActionResult Create1()

     {

     var model = new MasterM(); IFormatProvider UK = new CultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat; model.TrDate = (DateTime.Now.Date); return View(model); 

    }

       [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
     

      public ActionResult Create1(MasterM test)
        

    {
       var datet11 = test.TrDate;
       }


------------------------------startup

     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        
        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");
                options.SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("en-US") };
                options.SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("en-US") };
            });

          
            services.AddMvc(x => x.EnableEndpointRouting = false);

     
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(x =>
            {
                x.UseSqlServer(Configration.GetConnectionString("Contrings"));
            });
        }
```

Comment: No, the problem is that the property wasn't set so it kept its default value. `DateTime` is a value type and `0001-01-01 00:00:00` is its default value. Post the actual code that creates or modifies `model` and the date property

Comment: Is this an MVC or RazorPages application? `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TrDate` means you have a form that binds to a model, but where is this model set in the view or razor page? If MVC, does your action return a valid model? If Razor pages, does the handler modify the page model?

Comment: my action is very simple :   public ActionResult Create1()
        {


            var model = new MasterM();


            IFormatProvider UK = new CultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat;

            model.TrDate = (DateTime.Now.Date);


            return View(model);



        }

Comment: it is mvc i even tried with input put nothing work

Comment: We can't guess why code that wasn't posted isn't working. Post code that actually reproduces the problem, something that others can take and execute. Right now there's no view and the action is quirky. `new CultureInfo("en-US").` just creates new objects that aren't used. `DateTime` is a binary value. You could replace the action with `public ActionResult Create1()=>View(new MasterM{TrDate=DateTime.Today});` but is that method actually called? `Create1` may be a typo. We can't guess

Comment: i cant reveal all of it this is the best i can do

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use the bootstarp datepicker to set the datetime and then directly post it to the backend to see if this will work or not.

Add the script like below:

```
@section Scripts{

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script>
            $(function () {
                $('#TrDateInput').datetimepicker({
                    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A', // US date and time format
                  
                });
            });
    </script>

}
```

If this still not work, I suggest you could could use F12 network tool to see which exactly date formate the client post to the backend server which makes the auto model binding not work well.